# How to reduce/prevent the Wither effect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I found a Nether fortress, got in, found the two Blaze spawners, got hit by some Blaze fireballs, killed the Blazes and got some blaze rods and experience orbs, then went wandering in the fortress, found some Nether Warts, dug some Nether Bricks, got shot by more blazes, killing them again, being shot by some skeletons, killing them and getting some bones, and finally I saw two Wither Skeletons.

I quickly hold <kbd>S</kbd> to stay away from them (they are chasing me), get my nice diamond sword ready and fight...

They hit me fast and my health bar turned black and those nice hearts start leaving me. I get affected by the wither effect!

After some fight, I finally killed both of them and get the drops including a piece of stupid coal. My health is getting low (I am a coward, so I set mode to easy and I didn't die that fast) but it regenerates, thanks to my full hunger bar.

---

OK, end of the bedtime story, let's get to the real question: **Is there any factors that prevents the wither effect from affecting me or can I reduce the effect or make them stop faster?** Any potions/armor/whatever?

(The same should apply to the wither effect caused by Withers?)

Comment: Now that we have lingering potions, that should help against wither fights, also use healing splash/linger potions or arrows as they damage the undead --- blinding/slowing them can help too especially if you use ranged attacks though I doubt that would be very useful for melee attacks.  Buoyancy might help confuse them further.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [this table of status effects](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effects) from the wiki, a [potion of regeneration](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potions) or a [golden apple](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Golden_Apple) will give you regeneration for a short time, which should heal hearts over time faster than you lose them from the wither effect (1 gained every 25 ticks from the regeneration versus 1 lost every 40 ticks from the withering).

Also, drinking a [bucket of milk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Milk) can remove all status effects.

Comment: Oh, milk can remove all status effects? reading [Milk](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Milk) "curing poison and potion effects" - it didn't say the wither effect, but it worked. Also, nowhere in the wiki seems to have linked to the page [Status effect](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Status_effects)? Well I'm gonna make some edits...

Comment: BTW milk doesn't actually reduce/prevent the effect, but removes it. Since it at least solves the problem, I could accept this. (Though I don't think there is time to drink milk if being attacked by multiple wither skeletons.)

Answer (score 1):

Use potion of healing to heal you  but damage withers or wither skeleton or zombie or skeletons

Answer (score 0):

To not get caught under the Wither debuff you'll have to use this tactic when killing an Enderman. Basically, you can dog down and block them, you can hit them in the feet or the head by jumping over them. You could also use a bow and fight them at range. If you're under the wither effect you could eat either a Golden Apple or drink Milk to cure it.

Comment: Can you use some punctuation? It's hard to understand as it is.

Comment: @pinckerman Seriously? You have reputation and you're afraid of editing an answer for the sake of another user?

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m I'm not afraid, I'm just saying that punctuation is important.

Comment: Then use your 5k rep and edit the question. You go through the review queue and instead if leaving an edit you decide to leave a comment.

Comment: Between a) talking about Endermen, b) me not having the slightest idea what "dogging down" is supposed to mean, c) blocking not preventing the wither effect, IIRC, d) the middle part just describing how to use a sword and e) the last sentence being already included in the accepted answer, the only *useful* part of this answer is the advice to go ranged instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is indirect, but a Purplicious Cow Pet gives on-going health regeneration when in hot bar. You have to be carrying diamond nuggets. Be careful that you are not carrying buckets - it fills them with lava.

Comment: I believe your talking about mods,  this question was about vanilla minecraft. No need to bump a question several years old if it has a good answer that's still valid either..